# Could not reach the SOAP API action through washout gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, soap, salesforce, wash-out

I am trying to integrate the salesforce with my rails 6 application with the help of Washout
(0.12.0), and Savon
The issue is that I am not able to reach any action within the web service I have created by Washout and Savon gem. 
Further code related details are mentioned follows:

```
require 'savon'
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/https'
require 'errors'
require 'wash_out'

class Api::MyController < ActionController::Base
  soap_service namespace: 'urn:WashOut'

  before_action :dump_parameters

  def dump_parameters
    logger.info "Inside dump parameters"
    logger.info "Parameters: #{request}"
    logger.info "Parameters: #{request.raw_post}"
    my_params = params[:my_params]
    Rails.logger.info "End of dump paramaters"
  end
end
```

When the request is generated I cannot reach this controller or any action within it. 
The error I am getting after generating request from salesforce to my rails application.

```
Started POST "/api/my_controller/action" for 80.194.71.208 at 2020-02-04 18:15:43 +0530
Cannot render console from 80.194.71.208! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by Api::MyController#_invalid_action as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1236)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

wash_out (0.11.0) lib/wash_out/dispatcher.rb:34:in `_map_soap_parameters'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
```

And routes are as follows:

```
namespace :api do
  wash_out :my_controller
end
```